# How to make [example] extension method more generic/functional/efficient?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, extension-methods

I needed a double[] split into groups of x elements by stride y returning a List. Pretty basic...a loop and/or some linq and your all set. However, I have not been spending much time on extension methods and this looked like a good candidate for some practice. The **naive version** returns what I am looking for in my current application....

```
(A)
public static IList<T[]> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int every, int take)
{
  /*... throw E if X is insane ...*/
  var result = source
               .Where ((t, i) => i % every == 0)
               .Select((t, i) => source.Skip(i * every).Take(take).ToArray())
               .ToList();
  return result;
}
```

...the return type is sort of generic...*depending on your definition of generic*.

I would think...

```
(B)    
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>
                  (this IEnumerable<T> source,int every, int take){/*...*/}
```

...is a better solution...maybe.

**Question(s):**

- Is (B) preferred ?...Why ?
- How would you cast (B) as `IList <T[]>` ?
- Any benefit in refactoring ? *possibly
  two methods that might be chained or the like.*
- Is the approach sound ?...or have I
  missed something basic.

Comments, opinions and harsh language are always appreciated.

*Usage Context: C# .Net 4.0*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B is probably the better option. Really the major change is that the consumer of the code has the option to make it a list using ToList() on the end of your method, instead of being forced to deal with a List (an IList, actually, which cannot be iterated).

This has a LOT of advantages in method chaining and general use. It's easy to ToList() an enumerable, but hard to go the other way. So, you can call Select().Split().OrderBy() on a list and use the results in a foreach statement without having to have Linq iterate through the whole thing at once.

Refactoring to `yield return` single values MIGHT get you a performance bonus, but since you're basically just returning the iterator that the Select gave you (which will yield one item at a time itself) I don't think you'll get much benefit in yielding through it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer (B) as it looks more flexible. One way of casting the output of the (B) method to an `IList<T[]>` is as simple as chaining `.Select(x => x.ToArray()).ToList()` to it, e.g.,

```
var foo = 
    bar.Split(someEvery, someTake).Select(x => x.ToArray()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

In .Net 4, you can just change the return type to `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` and it will work.

Before .Net 4, you would have to cast the internal lists to `IEnumerable` first, by just calling `.Cast<IEnumerable<T>>()` on your `result` before returning.

Comment: Why call `Cast` instead of simply removing the `ToArray` and `ToList` calls?

Comment: @jball: There is a legitimate difference if you want the query to eagerly execute.

Comment: @Ani, it seems to defy the expectations of LINQ and extension methods to make an extension method that eagerly executes.

Comment: I was just concerned with translating the existing behavior, but, I agree with @jball that you should probably just remove the initial `ToArray` and `ToList` calls.

Comment: @jball: I agree with you that it is unusual; I was only pointign out a scenario where you would *want* to do it. Also, if I saw an extension that had return-type `IList<..>`, I would *expect* that it was executing eagerly .